# Lipschitz continuity of an implicit function generated by a monotonic and Lipschitz multivariate function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $z=F(x,y)$ be a function from $\mathbb R^d\times \mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ satisfying the following conditions:

- $z=F(x,y)$ is Lipschitz continuous w.r.t. $(x,y)$;
- Given $x$, $F(x,y)$ is non-decreasing w.r.t $y$ (not necessarily strictly increasing);
- For any $x\in\mathbb R^d$, there is a unique $y$ such that $F(x,y)=0$;

Based on the above conditions, $F(x,y)=0$ is an implicit function, denoted as $y=y(x)$. Can we prove that $y=y(x)$ is also Lipschitz continuous? Thank you!

A highly related problem: [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394484/lipschitz-continuity-of-an-implicit-function). It is shown that the answer is negative without the condition that $F(x,y)$ is non-decreasing w.r.t $y$.

Comment: $x+y^2$ for $0\le y\le1$, $x+y$ otherwise. Please note that this forum is for research-level questions, only. Homework is on-topic on https://math.stackexchange.com/